# Order in std::set and difference to std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers, stdset

I expected the order of `std::set` to be consistent like `std::list` or `std::vector`, only that a value will not be appended a second time. MSVC 110 prooved me wrong. I expected the following code the yield the result shown below, which is the case when running the code on ideone (http://ideone.com/e47GwQ) (not sure which compiler and version they use, though).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template <typename C>
int insert_get_index(C& container, typename C::value_type value)
{
    typename C::iterator it = container.insert(value).first;
    return std::distance(container.begin(), it);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3, b = 1, c = 9;
    std::set<int*> set;

    std::cout << insert_get_index(set, &a) << "\n";
    std::cout << insert_get_index(set, &b) << "\n";
    std::cout << insert_get_index(set, &c) << "\n";
    std::cout << insert_get_index(set, &a) << "\n";
    std::cout << insert_get_index(set, &b) << "\n";
    std::cout << insert_get_index(set, &c) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
```

Running the code in Visual Studio 2012 yields what you can see below.

```
0
0
2
1
0
2
```

Now, why did I thin that `std::set` behaves like described above? Because cplusplus.com states

> Sets are containers that store unique elements following a specific order.

and additionally, there is `std::unordered_set`.

1. Did I understand the documentation incorrectly and `std::set` is instead **value ordered**?
2. And what's `std::unordered_set` for then?
3. Is there a different standard library container that fulfils my requirements?

Comment: "Is there a different standard library container that fulfils my requirements?" - what are your requirements?

Comment: @MikeSeymour As described above, I expected `std::set` to keep the order in which values are inserted, but insert them only once. That is my requirement.

Comment: `std::set` is an ordered associative container usually implemented with a red-black tree.

Comment: @T.C. I've red this before, too. But it is not specified in what "order" (edit: or I've missed it, in which case I'm sorry).

Comment: Ordered using the comparator you supplied when you created the set. By default it's `std::less<T>`.

Comment: @NiklasR: The order defined by comparing the values using `<` (or a user-provided comparator). In this case, the values are pointers, so the order depends on the pointer values; that is, where on the stack the compiler decides to store the three variables.

Comment: @MikeSeymour `std::less` supplies a total order for all pointers; `<` doesn't necessarily do that.

Comment: @SteveJessop `<` to compare pointers outside of the fully specified cases is unspecified, not undefined.

Comment: @T.C.: Sorry, I slightly sacrificed accuracy to make the comment readable. For the benefit of pedants: "the order defined by comparing the values using `std::less`, which for most types uses `<`, but also defines an ordering for pointers which can't generally be compared with `<`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did I understand the documentation incorrectly and std::set is instead value ordered?

It is indeed ordered by value. Unless you provide your own comparator, they are ordered by comparing them using `std::less`. For most types, this uses `<`. For pointers (which can't generally be compared with `<` in a well-defined way), it defines an unspecified but consistent ordering. (On common platforms with a linear address space, this would probably simply compare address values; but you can't rely on that).

So in this case, storing pointers to local variables, it depends on where the compiler chooses to allocate storage for each variable, which could vary from compiler to compiler.

> And what's `std::unordered_set` for then?

When you don't care about the order, this can give better performance. It uses a hash table to give constant-time lookup, while `set` uses a search tree (or something similar) to give logarithmic-time lookup.

> Is there a different standard library container that fulfils my requirements?

No, there's no container that both maintains insertion order, and provides fast value-based lookup. Depending on your exact requirements, you might use `vector` to maintain the order, and put up with a linear-time lookup using `std::find`; or you might use two containers, one to maintain the order and one to provide fast lookup, with careful logic to keep them consistent.

Comment: ... or use Boost.MultiIndex to take care of the consistency for you.

Comment: Thank you @MikeSeymour, for this thorough and understandable answer. I use an `std::vector` now.